# How to use the setenv function?

Tags: c++, linux

I am currently using the `chdir`  and `getenv` functions in order to implement the bash commands `cd` and `cd <path>`. I am also required to use the `setenv` function, however I am not able to understand how this function is used.

The other command I have to implement is `cd -`, so I'm wondering if it can just be implemented using the first two functions if I find a way to keep access OLDPWD or if this is what `setenv` is used for.

Comment: The function documentation should explain what `setenv` does. Do you need this functionality? (ie. modifying the *current processes* environment variables?)

Comment: You haven't explained your situation very well.  I'm guessing you're writing an extremely minimal shell, and as such if the user types `ABC=123` you should call `setenv("ABC", "123", 1);`.  For `cd -`, you will need to store the old working directory somewhere; a setenv of OLDPWD is a reasonable option, but a variable in your program might suffice too.

Comment: @TonyD I'm just adding on these three `cd` commands to a simple shell I've created. I'm going to try a 'setenv` of OLDPWD, thank you your example helped clarifying things.

Answer (score 0):

To implement `cd`, you need to know `$HOME`. To implement `cd <path>`, you need to know `$PWD`. You can get `$HOME` and `$PWD` with `getenv`

Comment: I already have successfully implemented those commands, I'm just having trouble with `cd -` and am wondering if `setenv` has to do with it.

Comment: just track the last visited directory in your program.